# Issue YOLO giving Illegal instruction (core dumped) on Jetson Nano

Tags: python, nvidia, core-dump, opencv

I have a jetson nano and I have Ubuntu 18.04 installed running JetPack 4.6. I am trying to run a object detection program from a camera on it.

I had a bit of a funky installation process:

- I installed python3 (not in a virtual environment)
- Then installed a few libraries before realizing I needed python 3.8 or greater to use ultralytics and torch
- I installed python3.8 and created an alias called python31 that would run python3.8
- I used opencv to grab my webcams input and it worked
- I tried installing torch and it didn't work so I moved to creating a virtual environment in python 3.8
- I installed torch and ultralytics in the virtual environment but for some reason torch was installed outside the environment as well so I decided to also install ultralytics outside the environment.
- I tested if ultralytics and torch were present on both the vm and outside by using .**version** and it worked, the versions also matched. (torch version 2.1.2, torchvision 0.16.2, ultralytics ver 8.0.235, opencv-python 0.16.2)
- I tried running this code and the imports went smoothly, however, I get an Illegal instruction (core dumped) fault when I run this on code-oss

```
import cv2
import sys
from ultralytics import YOLO
print(cv2.__version__)
model = YOLO("yolo-Weights/yolov8n.pt")
classNames = ["person", "bicycle", "car", "motorbike", "aeroplane", "bus", "train", "truck", "boat",
              "traffic light", "fire hydrant", "stop sign", "parking meter", "bench", "bird", "cat",
              "dog", "horse", "sheep", "cow", "elephant", "bear", "zebra", "giraffe", "backpack", "umbrella",
              "handbag", "tie", "suitcase", "frisbee", "skis", "snowboard", "sports ball", "kite", "baseball bat",
              "baseball glove", "skateboard", "surfboard", "tennis racket", "bottle", "wine glass", "cup",
              "fork", "knife", "spoon", "bowl", "banana", "apple", "sandwich", "orange", "broccoli",
              "carrot", "hot dog", "pizza", "donut", "cake", "chair", "sofa", "pottedplant", "bed",
              "diningtable", "toilet", "tvmonitor", "laptop", "mouse", "remote", "keyboard", "cell phone",
              "microwave", "oven", "toaster", "sink", "refrigerator", "book", "clock", "vase", "scissors",
              "teddy bear", "hair drier", "toothbrush"
              ]
window_title = "USB camera"
camera_id = "/dev/video0"
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(camera_id, cv2.CAP_V4L2)
video_capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG'))
video_capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
video_capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480)
video_capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 30)
while True:
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()
    results = model(frame, stream=True)
    for r in results:
        boxes = r.boxes
        for box in boxes:
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = box.xyxy[0]
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = int(x1), int(y1), int(x2), int(y2)
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255, 0, 255), 3)
            con = math.ceil((box.conf[0]*100))/100
            print(con)
            classs = int(box.cls[0])
            org = [x1, y1]
            font = cv2.FONT_HERSEY_SIMPLEX
            fontScale = 1
            color = (255, 0, 0)
            thickness = 2
            cv2.putText(img, classNames[classs], org, font, fontScale, color, thickness)

    cv2.imshow('JetCam', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Terminal Out:
4.9.0

Illegal instruction (core dumped)

I was wondering how I could diagnose this error and ways to fix it. Thanks!